# Really slow sql for search result count (for paging)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains many news. I'm using SQL Server 2008 Standard ed

In this table, I have

- *2 millions* rows
- clustered index is on a `datetime` column which indicate record insert time.
- nonclustered index on `headline` column, `newsIdentity` column (maybe duplicate), `author` column

When I search news in this table ***through my web app***, the server need more than 20 sec to responds.

I found the SQL for counting the number of rows is really slow (for search result paging).

Here's the **showplan_text** results:

StmtText

```
select count(*) 
from [news] WITH (NOLOCK)       
WHERE headline like N'%Nginx%'
```

StmtText

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1007],0))) 
   |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=Count(*))) 
        |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([newsMangr].[dbo].[news].[IX_SearchNews]),  WHERE:  ([newsMangr].[dbo].[news].[headline] like N'%Nginx%'))
```

20 sec is unacceptable, any suggestions?

Comment: Show us example of news content? Is "Nginx" substring on constant offset?

Comment: Well, by using the `LIKE N'%ginx%'` (with a leading `%`) you're making **sure** that SQL Server **cannot** possibly use any indexes..... this is causing the slowness - it needs to scan the **entire table** to find the rows matching your `headline`.

Comment: Can you add a calculated persisted field that has your criteria already preloaded?

Comment: @marc_s can full text indexing help for index seek?

Comment: @mr_eclair: fulltext searching *can* help - but it's **word-based**, e.g. you can easily search for words - but not really fragments of words

Comment: @marc_s what about **like 'scott%'**, still table scan?

Comment: @Scott混合理论: if you **don't** have a leading `%`, then **yes** an index might be used (if it's useful to the query optimizer)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(headline, <offset>, 5) = 'Nginx'
```

Where `<offset>` is constant value.

Comment: Hi @k06a, i don't think i can get offset from user, they can search any words in any position through my web app.

Comment: In order to accomplish things like that toy have to use FullText search.